# Trying to deploy django app on heroku. Foreman is not recognized

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to complete [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) tutorial and I when I run foreman start, I get an error saying

> 'foreman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I tried instaling foreman by `pip install foreman` but it says

> No distributions at all found for foreman

How can I fix this ? I'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Heroku toolbelt? Note that it's different from the django-toolbelt from the tutorial, even though the names are similar enough to be confusing. If not, get the toolbelt here and try again: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Comment: yes I have installed heroku toolbelt and I can run heroku commands from commandline

Comment: Is the foreman application installed, i.e. can you see the executable in the installation directory? Is the path correctly set?